# Finding 2D contour area when contour contains edges of domain

Tags: matlab, area

Say we have the following in MATLAB:

```matlab
xs = -50:50;
ys = -50:50;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(xs,ys);
rs = (X.^2 + Y.^2).^(1/2);
c = contourf(X,Y,rs,[60,60]);
```

How do I estimate the area of the white area?

This is a test case, usually I do not know the equation for the level set.

Note that the level set intersects with the boundary, and I cannot just increase the domain size to avoid that (in the non-test case).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** If you want to approximate the white area also **beyond the boundaries**, then the below approach obviously won't work. I just realized, there's scope of interpretation regarding your wording.

---

If you at least know the threshold contour level (here it seems to be `60`) than you can just count the amount of "pixels" below that threshold, and calculate the area with respect to `x` and `y`.

Here's some exemplary code (I modified your code, too):

```matlab
x = -50:0.1:50;
y = -50:0.1:50;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
Z = (X.^2 + Y.^2).^(1/2);
c = contourf(X, Y, Z, [60, 60]);
colorbar();

% Total amount of pixels representing the area
a_pixels_total = length(x) * length(y)

% Amount of pixels below given contour level
a_pixels_below = sum(Z(:) <= 60)

% Total area in units
a_unit_total = (x(end) - x(1)) * (y(end) - y(1))

% Percentage of area below the given contour level in units 
a_unit_perc = a_pixels_below / a_pixels_total * a_unit_total
```

The output then is:

```
a_pixels_total =  1002001
a_pixels_perc =  952233
a_unit_total =  10000
a_unit_perc =  9503.3
```

Hope that helps!